# Logo and title in actionbar in android

Tags: android, xml, styles, android-actionbar

I use action bar in my app (actionbarsherlock) and I wanted I wanted the title not to be shown but just wiew the logo in ab. So I tried to use

```
<item name="abDisplayOptions">useLogo</item>
```

Yes, the title disappeared, but the logo isn't shown anymore. Why? And how can I solve it using just XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I've solved this problem by

`<item name="abIcon">@drawable/logo</item>`

and then

`<item name="abDisplayOptions">showHome</item>`

But I do not understand why it didn't work with abLogo.